# Fullcalendar Scheduler - multiple user view not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm trying to get a multiple user views using Scheduler. This is the code I'm using:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            events: [
                // events go here
            ],
            resources: [
                { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
                { id: 'b', title: 'Room B' },
                { id: 'c', title: 'Room C' },
                { id: 'd', title: 'Room D' }
            ]
            // other options go here...
        });
```

However this isn't working, it's not displaying multiple users, just the AgendaDay view.

I'm also getting an error in my console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Mixin' of undefined

I don't know if this is what's causing the problem.
I installed fullcalendar and scheduler from npm install, I'm not importing any links in my head.

So my question is if my code isn't working because of the shown error or because of something else?
If it is because of the mixin error I'd like to see some possible fixes, I've already tried the other fixes on this but they don't seem to work.

This is the error that is given by scheduler.js

[image]

Comment: See my answer below regarding setting up the view. Your console error is seemingly unrelated - maybe some other JS in your page is causing that. There's nothing called "Mixin" related to fullCalendar AFAIK.

Comment: I think you're right about Fullcalendar not having any mixins, but scheduler does, thats also where my error is coming from. I've tried your solution but this still doesn't work for me. So my concern is that the issue is within the error i mentioned in my question.

Comment: Exactly where is the error coming from? What's the stack trace?

Comment: I have included the stacktrace in my question.

Comment: ok can you please confirm what version of jQuery, momentJS, fullCalendar and Scheduler you are using? How are you including them in your page? And please show the whole of your calendar setup code.

Comment: I think i know why im getting this error and im currently looking into it. Ill let you know if this doesn't work out, and if it does ill be sure to post the solution. Thanks for helping me out so far!

Answer (score 1):

Get the fullcalendar v3 or above. It doesn't work in v2 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view, if you want the agenda-style views to split the view by resource, you need to specify the groupByResource option as well in your calendar setup:

```
groupByResource: true
```

This will group the view by resource, and then by date.

Or alternatively you can set groupByDateAndResource instead, if you prefer to group by date and then resource:

```
groupByDateAndResource: true
```

Having said that, of course for an agendaDay view, it will not make any difference because there is only one date to display.